# Navigate back and show snack

Tags: dart, flutter

I am thinking of this pattern for my application, and cannot find a proper way of doing it.
User is in list page, she clicks on an item and goes to edit page. She edits, and hits the save. Now I want the application to 
- show spinning wheel, while saving the item
- after save pop the route to go back to list page, AND show a snackbar on the list page. 
I don't seem to find a way to pass a parameter to the previous route to tell it about the state, which is to show the snackbar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For showing progress on click of save button you can use something like this.
Firstly initialize a variable `static bool isSaving = false;` then in your scaffold use it like this.

```
child:Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
      isSaving
          ? new Container(
              child: new CircularProgressIndicator(
                value: null,
                strokeWidth: 2.0,
              ),
              alignment: Alignment.center,
            )
          : new Container(
              child: new RaisedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    isSaving = true;
                    //Other Implementations here
                  });
                },
                child: new Text("Save"),
              ),
            ),
    ],
  ),
```

When the operation is complete again set state and make variable false.
Now when you get notified that operation has been done use Navigator to go back.

```
Navigator.pop(context);
```

For showing snackbar in your previous screen use a [GlobalKey](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GlobalKey-class.html).

```
GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
```

Assign this key to your scaffold.

```
new Scaffold(
    key: scaffoldKey,
    ...
    )
```

As answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47914739/show-a-snackbar-after-navigate?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) show snackbar just after pop operation like this.

```
scaffoldKey.currentState
    .showSnackBar(new SnackBar(content: new Text("Saved Successfully")));
```

Or can try a different approach as explained in this [sample](https://flutter.io/cookbook/navigation/returning-data/).
Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks! But how do I tell the page that I poped into that it needs to show the snackbar? it doesn't always needs to show that

Comment: If you just want to show the snackbar then there is no need to tell the page about that. Just use `scaffoldKey`. But if you want specific operation on pop then use the other approach(sample).

Comment: Moreover `Globalkey` can be accessed anywhere in the application.

Answer (score 1):

You can send data back through pop method. You can do something like that.

In your edit page:

```dart
bool saved = item.save();
Navigator.pop(context, saved);
```

In your list page:

```dart
var saved = await Navigator.push(
  context, 
  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => EditRoute(item)),
);
if (saved) {
  // Show success snackbar
} else {
  // Show error snackbar
}
```

Comment: I'm getting the following error using this solution: `Scaffold.geometryOf() must only be accessed during the paint phase.`