# Show a flushbar after navigate in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have same question as [Show a snackbar after navigate in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47914739/show-a-snackbar-after-navigate-in-flutter) but for https://pub.dev/packages/flushbar

How can I show flushbar after navigation?

(In first route, when we navigate to second route, we have a background task, the task may fail, I want to show a message to end usee by flush bar,  UI is in SecondRoute (or may be another route) and In FiratRout after (or before , no matter) navigation, background task runned and after a while may be failed

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    title: 'Navigation Basics',
    home: FirstRoute(),
  ));
}

class FirstRoute extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('First Route'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          child: Text('Open route'),
          onPressed: () async {
            await Navigator.pushReplacement(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondRoute()),
            );
            Flushbar(
              title: "Hey Ninja",
              message:
                  "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry",
              duration: Duration(seconds: 3),
            )..show(context);
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SecondRoute extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Second Route"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text(
            "I want to show here Flushbar, Flushbar.show called in FirstRoute"),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: did you try as in that question's answer showed ?

Comment: also add getSavedThingRoute().

Comment: I have `Scaffold` in each route and it is not possible to set GlobalKey for all of them , Also `scaffoldKey.currentState` has no flushbar! As I am newbie in flutter I have no idea!

Comment: @VirenVVarasadiya `getSavedThingRoute()` is a fake example , it is not important , I just want to show flushbar without context

Comment: can you try just putting await before navigator ? await  Navigator.....

Comment: I added await , snackbar not shown , If I move it upper than Navigator it shown , But question it showing it without context

Answer (score 3):

You can show flushbar after navigating by using

`SchedulerBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback();`

So, your onPressed code will be something like this.

```
await Navigator.pushReplacement(
  context,
  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondRoute()),
);
SchedulerBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
  Flushbar(
    title: "Hey Ninja",
    message:
    "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry",
    duration: Duration(seconds: 3),
  )..show(context);
});
```

Hope it works.

Answer (score 1):

```
Navigator.push()
```

is a `Future` type so awaiting it should be all you need as long as you are returning back to the widget you pushed from.

Example with regular snackbar:

```
Future routeAndShowSnack() async {
   await Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => OtherWidget(param: value))
   );
   _scaffoldKey.currentState.show(SnackBar(content: Text('Heres a snack'));
}
```

You need to make sure the context you are calling scaffold with is the correct context. If you are calling context above the scaffold then it will fail gracefully and not show a snackbar. Please show `Widget build()` code if you are unsure about the scaffold context.

NOTE: I just copied this code from a repo I have. You do not need to route with the material page route builder widget.

Example below of what you are trying to achieve.

```
class FirstRoute extends StatefulWidget {
  FirstRoute({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _FirstRouteState createState() => _FirstRouteState();
}

class _FirstRouteState extends State<FirstRoute> {
  final  GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _keyin = GlobalKey();

  void _flush(BuildContext context) async {
    await Navigator.of(context).push(
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondRoute()),
    );
    Flushbar(
      title: "Hey Ninja",
      message:
          "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry",
      duration: Duration(seconds: 3),
    )..show(context);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _keyin,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () => _flush(context),
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SecondRoute extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: OutlineButton(
          child: Text('Back'), 
          onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop()
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

As I commented below, you cannot achieve this functionality with `pushReplacement` as that breaks the concept of waiting for a route to return back to the initial route. If you replace a route in the navigator tree then anything you wanted to run has been disposed of.

Comment: What if I don't use `Navigator.push`  and use `pushReplacementNamed` ?

Comment: Where you set _scaffoldKey?

Comment: pushReplacementNamed might only work if there is a route to back navigate to. Can you please show your widget code so I can see the context being used for scaffold? I can show you how to use the GlobalKey for scaffold also

Comment: see https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigation-basics , in FirstRoute's onPressed , I want to pushReplacementNamed to SecondRoute  then show Flushbar not SnackBar

Comment: Ok you cannot use `pushReplacement` because then you cannot navigate back to the FirstRoute. If you are replacing the route in the navigator tree how could it possibly return to the FirstRoute? Example of using Navigator.push() above which I have verified does work on my local machine.

Comment: I dont want to navigate back, I want to show flushbar in second route from the first route,in first route we have a background task, it may fail, I want to show snackbar that ot failed, but UI is in second(or may be another) route